# Switching the order of columns of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, multiple-columns

Suppose I generate the following fictional matrix

```
mat <-matrix(1:12,3)
```

Now I would like to rearrange the order of the columns from 1:4 to 4:1

Manually I could do this by.

```
Z <- cbind(mat[,4],mat[,3],mat[,2],mat[,1])
```

Now when the matrix becomes large with for example 30 columns, doing this manually will be a tedious process.

Does anyone have a suggestion to rewrite the order of the columns with for example a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use indexing i.e. create a sequence (`:`) from the last column index - `ncol(mat)` to 1 and use that as column index

```
mat[, ncol(mat):1]
```

Or with `rev`

```
mat[, rev(seq_len(ncol(mat)))]
```